# Hide map popup in map v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Hello friends. I want to hide my popup in map v2 when I click in particular marker on map.
below is my code:

```
public class DemopMap extends FragmentActivity  {


GoogleMap googleMap;
Button button1;
Marker startPerc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demomap);

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        startPerc = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(62.2270,105.3809))
        .title("Demo"));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(62.2270,105.3809), 5.0f));

        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                 marker.hideInfoWindow();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "InfoWindowAdapter", 2000).show();
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                 marker.hideInfoWindow();
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_map, null);
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // Getting reference to the TextView to set title
                TextView note = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView snip = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                snip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return v;

            }

        });
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }
    }       
}
```

}

**row file for marker**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

When I click marker I display like as below:

[image]

so any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Don't want to show InfoWindow of marker??

Comment: @Lokesh Yes  i Don't want to show InfoWindow of marker

Comment: An info window can be hidden by calling hideInfoWindow(). Check this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#showhide_an_info_window

Answer (score 0):

I just add this line and it work for me

googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

```
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arg0.hideInfoWindow();
                return true;
            }
        });
```